# recvfrom unexpected error: Invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

I'm writing a server-client application using UDP protocol. When I run the `recvfrom` I get the following error and I really can't understand why:

> recvfrom: Invalid argument

Here's what I assumed is the code relative to this error:

```
#define CLIE_PORT 5499
#define MAXMSGSIZE (1024 * 1024) // Max message size is 1MB
#define CLIE_PORT 5499
#define PACKETSZ 7
```

I'm running `rcv_string` in this way:

```
char *result = malloc(MAXMSGSIZE);
struct sockaddr_in sndaddr;
rcv_string((uint16_t) CLIE_PORT, &result, &sndaddr);
```

Here's the implementation of `rcv_string` (inside there's the call to `recvfrom`).

```
int rcv_string(uint16_t port, char **return_string, struct sockaddr_in *sndaddr) {
    // [...]
    memset((char *) sndaddr, 0, sizeof(*sndaddr));
    (*sndaddr).sin_family = AF_INET;
    (*sndaddr).sin_port = htons(port);
    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd_in, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return -1;
    }
    if (bind(sockfd_in, (struct sockaddr *) sndaddr, sizeof(*sndaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        return -1;
    }
    socklen_t len;
    if ((recvfrom(sockfd_in, buff, PACKETSZ + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) sndaddr, &len)) < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            return -1;
        }
    // [...]
}
```

What could be the problem? (If you think I should upload more code, tell me!)

Comment: What is `len`? You do initialize it to the size of `*sndaddr`? And what is `sockfd_in`? How do you initialize it? Lastly please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you calling `malloc` before calling this `rcv_string` function, and then passing a pointer to the pointer seems suspect. Do you reassign `*return_string` inside the function? Do you remember to `free` the already allocated memory first?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for your answer, I updated the OP with some more code, I don't initialize `len`, should I? Yes `*return_string` is being modified inside the function. Where should I use `free`? Sorry I'm a little confused.

Comment: Yes you need to initialize `len`. And regarding `*return_string`, it points to memory you have allocated with `malloc` right? Now what happens if you do `*return_string = something_else;`? You *lose* the original memory you allocated.

Comment: Initializing `len` solved the issue, thanks @Someprogrammerdude! If you make an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `socklen_t len=sizeof(*sndaddr);`.